# CURL PHP MyGate Payment gateway

Tags: php, curl, https, payment-gateway

I am trying to post some details to mygate payment gateway.
If i use a normal form and post to the url, it generates a token id for that specific session and internally redirects the page to the details capturing page.

As i am using curl to do so, i get a success message but i am unable to get the required page.

Is it possible to load the same page in a new tab using curl, I suspect that would help me in some way.

Any other solution would also be appreciated.

Code i have tried is:

```
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,0);

    //turning off the server and peer verification(TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);       


    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$result)
    {
        echo curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        echo $result;
    }

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What kind of success message do you get.

Comment: By success message i meant was, i get the value of $result as 1,

Also if i test it with google it works perfectly fine.

Comment: hm what dou you have in $field_string?

Comment: while using curl you will get only response by url,altenatively you can use file_get_contents. you will not load that page but will show the html content of that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its redirecting to a page on success, You can get the location of the redirected url.

You can get the redirect URL by setting some curl options.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$a = curl_exec($ch);
if(preg_match('#Location: (.*)#', $a, $r))
 $l = trim($r[1]);
```

`$l` would be the redirect location. You can get the url and redirect your page to the location.

$r will contain an array with location url.